# Angular Universal not loading child modules

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I have few modules in my angular app. The app itself is working good with ng build and ng serve and stuff like that. Now I would like to implement Angular Universal. When there are no modules npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr is working good. Since I have modules, npm run build:ssr couldn't load the modules for the app.

I have tried different solutions from Google, but nothing seems to be working.

My ServerModule:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    StModule,
    ServerModule,
    ModuleMapLoaderModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [StComponent],
})
export class StServerModule {}
```

main.server.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

export { StServerModule } from './st/st.server.module';
```

tsconfig.server.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/st-server",
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "st/st.server.module#StServerModule"
  }
}
```

My other modules in the app are
    AdminModule
    CommonModule
    CoreModule

The above modules were not been loaded by npm run and was throwing errors.

Comment: where is your routing module